# TSheets overtime via API?

Tags: php, quickbooks

A client using tsheets has to run two CSV reports and then combine them and rename in Excel so they have approached me to build it as part of their web app.

One of the reports is the payroll report that shows the overtime under column type and with values REG, OT 1.5 etc

Has anyone been able to get this information via the API?

I tried [retrieve-payroll-by-jobcode-report](https://tsheetsteam.github.io/api_docs/#retrieve-payroll-by-jobcode-report) however that seems to return an empty array when testing

```
define('API_URL', 'https://rest.tsheets.com/api/v1/');
$api_token = TSHEET_ACCESS_TOKEN;
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: Bearer {$api_token}";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

define('CURL_HEADER', $ch);
$ch = CURL_HEADER;
$params = '?start_date=' . $start_date . '&end_date=' . $end_date;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, API_URL . 'payroll_by_jobcode' . $params);
$o = curl_exec($ch);
$o = json_decode($o);

var_dump($o);die();
```

I am able to get all the other data I need for the app so I know my API is working and fetching the data so any thoughts/advice appreciated.